# Show/hide items based on toggled values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, show-hide

My goal is to initially show all items, then hide/show them based on different properties that are toggled. I don't want to chain filters really because I just want to hide/show items that have matching properties. I have 4 buttons that handle the overall properties to filter on. I've tried various iterations, but it never turns out quite right.  What am I missing?

> $scope.radioModel = {     "isBoat": "1",  "isHome": "1",  "isCar": "1",
>       "hasEngine": "1" };

```
<button ng-click="update('isBoat')">Is a boat</button>
<button ng-click="update('isCar')">Is a car</button>
<button ng-click="update('hasEngine')">Has an engine</button>
<button ng-click="update('isHome')">Is a home</button>

$scope.update = function(key) {
    if($scope.radioModel[key] == '1') { 
        $scope.radioModel[key] = '0';
    }
    else {
        $scope.radioModel[key] = '1';
    }
};

$scope.items = [
    { "personid": 1, "itemName": "Car 1", "isCar": "1", "isBoat": "0", "isHome": "0", "hasEngine": "1" },
    { "personid": 2, "itemName": "Home 1", "isCar": "0", "isBoat": "0", "isHome": "1", "hasEngine": "0" },
    { "personid": 3, "itemName": "Car 2", "isCar": "1", "isBoat": "0", "isHome": "0", "hasEngine": "1" },
    { "personid": 1, "itemName": "Boat 1", "isCar": "0", "isBoat": "1", "isHome": "0", "hasEngine": "1" }
]
```

// show/hide items based on matching properties
// Each item can have several properties that are true

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in items | groupBy: 'personid'">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">
        {{v.itemName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

So if hasEngine is true, then all items with isEngine will show.

If isCar, hasEngine, and isHome are set to true, then show items that are a car, has an engine, or is a home

Comment: You could use a function to return an array of items that pass the current filters. For example, `ng-repeat='item in filteredItems()'` where `$scope.filteredItems = function() { return $scope.items.filter(...) }`. If this would work, I can elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom filter to filter data with your radioModel

add custom filter to your controller

```
 $scope.sampleFilter = function (item) {
      if(item.isCar == $scope.radioModel.isCar && item.isHome == $scope.radioModel.isHome && item.isBoat == $scope.radioModel.isBoat && item.hasEngine == $scope.radioModel.hasEngine){
        return true;
      }
      else
        return false;
  };
```

and add filter to your ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:sampleFilter">
    {{item.personid}}-{{item.itemName}}-{{item.isBoat}}-{{item.isCar}}-{{item.hasEngine}}-{{item.isHome}}
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/KSiDHgUU9c0vqn51WkEN?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want it to have to match all conditions though. For example, if i click isBoat and is home, it should show items [0], [2], and [4]....and not just item [0] which has all conditions

Comment: you can change the logic inside custom filter, instead of and (&&) if you use or (||) filter would display any item that satisfies one of the conditions.